# getEnhancedMicrophone() doesn't work (reduce echo) on air mobile for IOS

Tags: ios, mobile, video, air, chat

I have a problem with my flex mobile application on iOS. It is a video chat application with a red5 server.

The video works fine but the voice has a big echo! I tried using `getEnhancedMicrophone()` but it didn't help.

How can I have Acoustic Echo cancellation or suppression on IOS?

I work on Flash Builder 4.6 with Air 3.5

Comment: No developers in this area ?

Comment: I'm having the same issue, but on an Android tablet: Microphone.getEnhancedMicrophone() returns null.

Answer (score 3):

There no known solutions.

Adobe been promising a fix for years but the solution requires access to Android source code from Google that is not open source. I had the same issues with a videChat app on Android using Adobe Air. I tried as workaround:

1. Switching `mic.setLoopback(false/true)` in a timer to break up the audio
2. Trying to detect sound coming over NetStream and set the local device mic gain to 0
   Problem is I cannot detect if someone is talking over NetStream.
3. Use NetStreamInfo audio properties like `audioBytesPerSecond` but these do not jump when someone is talking over NetStream.
4. The problem is solved if the user wears headphones on the mobile side but this is not acceptable.